# I want to print my log when I click an object

Tags: javascript, automation, testcomplete

```
var tr= page.NativeWebObject.Find("id",document_tab,"a").Click();
          if(tr == true )
          {
            Log.Message("document module is visible ")
          }
```

I want to print this on link click.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that check if the document is opened in the following way:

```
var tr= page.NativeWebObject.Find("id",document_tab,"a").Click();
var doc = page.WaitPanel()//… obtain the path to the opened window and specify it here
          if(doc.Exists)
          {
            Log.Message("document module is visible ")
          }
```

Details: "Waiting for an Object, Process or Window Activation" - http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/56525/

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to find is that .Click() doesn't return anything.  It just clicks on an onscreen object.  If you want to log a message when you click on an item, go ahead and do it.  There's no fancy logic necessary.  But if you want to ensure something happened when you click that button, you need to check the object tree or check for some indication that something happened.